# Are there any NULL bytes in an MS Access database?

Tags: windows, database, mercurial

[Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/BinaryFiles) `diff`s files only if it is "not binary", where "binary" is defined as "contains a NULL byte".

Do databases in MS Access (`.mdb`) contain null bytes?

Comment: That was an overly simplistic definition. Clearly `diff` needs (as in: its intended use is for) pure text files. *.mdb files are not likely to adhere to that. For more insights in what files are "binary" - check [the man page for file](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?file).

Comment: @Hannu OK, I'm not going to argue Mercurial's point of view although they try to justify it in that link. `file Northwest.mdb` simply says "MS Access database".